# Как проверить, зашел ли пользователь с мобильного устройства или с компьютера?

Tags: jquery, mobile, javascript, php

В принципе, не имеет значения, может и сервер, может и клиентская сторона проверить. Вопрос только в том, как это сделать.

Comment: Уже было, [тыц](http://hashcode.ru/questions/70122/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверяйте содержимое `navigator.userAgent` на наличие подстрок "iphone", "android", "blackberry", "webos", и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Подделать можно устройство легко, не вариант
Если на стороне клиента то можно на js проверить размер экрана. Как сами понимаете у телефона или сматрфона экран будет меньше чем у ПК.
Сразу дам навочку, а дальше сами

```
<script>  
    width=screen.width; // ширина  
    height=screen.height; // высота  
    alert ("Разрешение экрана: "+width+"x"+height);   
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример на php (может кому в будущем пригодится). Взят с [этого сайта](https://vk-book.ru/opredelenie-mobilnogo-ustrojstva-v-php/). Пользую на своих проектах - работает.

```
// определение мобильного устройства
function check_mobile_device() { 
    $mobile_agent_array = array('ipad', 'iphone', 'android', 'pocket', 'palm', 'windows ce', 'windowsce', 'cellphone', 'opera mobi', 'ipod', 'small', 'sharp', 'sonyericsson', 'symbian', 'opera mini', 'nokia', 'htc_', 'samsung', 'motorola', 'smartphone', 'blackberry', 'playstation portable', 'tablet browser');
    $agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);    
    foreach ($mobile_agent_array as $value) {    
        if (strpos($agent, $value) !== false) return true;   
    }       
    return false; 
}

// пример использования
$is_mobile_device = check_mobile_device();
if($is_mobile_device){
    echo "Вы зашли с мобильного устройства";
}else{
    echo "Вы зашли с PC";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У Яндекса есть хороший API для определения мобильных устройств: [API Яндекс.Детектор](http://api.yandex.ru/detector/).

> PI Яндекс.Детектор предоставляет возможность определения модели и характеристик мобильного устройства пользователя сайта по заголовкам HTTP-запросов, передаваемых браузером его устройства.

Answer (score -1):

Браузер серверу отправляет вполне подробную информацию о самом себе, а уже на стороне сервера эту инфу проверять можно ...

Comment: а на стороне клиента?

Comment: На стороне клиента есть javascript

Answer (score -1):

- Определение мобильного браузера
- [**Detect Mobile Browsers**](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Наличие точек соприкосновения с экраном и смены ориентации экрана явно указывают на мобильное устройство:

```
mobile = navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 && 'orientation' in window
```

true (для мобильных устройств) / false (для десктопов)